# Definition of Smooth Homotopy

Tags: smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $N,M$ be smooth manifolds with or without boundary. Lee's ISM defines a smooth homotopy $H : N \times I \to M$ as a homotopy that extends to a smooth map in some neighborhood of $N \times I \subset N \times \mathbb{R}.$ Is this equivalent to requiring that $H$ be smooth, where $N \times I$ is interpreted as a manifold with boundary? My initial instinct is to say yes, but when unraveling definitions I'm having trouble making the jump from a smooth extension around each point on $\partial(N \times I)$ to a smooth extension around the entire $N \times I$.

EDIT: It just occurred to me that $N \times I$ will not be a manifold with boundary if $N$ itself has nonempty boundary, so my question will only apply to the case when $N$ has empty boundary.

EDIT 2: Here's the definition I'm working with for a smooth map on a manifold with boundary:

> Let $F : M \to N$ be a map, where $M$, $N$ are manifolds with boundary. $F$ is *smooth* if for all $p \in M$, there exist charts $(U,\phi : U \to \tilde{U} \subset \mathbb{H}^n \text{ or } \mathbb{R}^n)$ for $M$ containing $p$ and $(V,\psi : V \to \tilde{V} \subset \mathbb{H}^n \text{ or } \mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $F(U) \subset V$ and $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1} : \tilde{U} \to \tilde{V}$ is smooth as a map of Euclidean spaces. (If $\tilde{U} \subset \mathbb{H}^n$, we require that $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}$ extends to a smooth map in a neighborhood of each point in the domain.)

Comment: The answer depends on what definition you are using for a smooth map defined on a manifold with boundary; you should include that definition.

Comment: @LeeMosher Good point, just added the definition.

Comment: The next question is, what does it mean for the very last map to be smooth? The domain and range $\tilde U,\tilde V$ are not "all" of Euclidean space, of course, and they are not necessarily even open subsets of Euclidean space, not in the case where the target of the map is $\mathbb H^n$. So the manner in which smoothness is defined here is critical.

Comment: We can easily make the range all of Euclidean space by composing with the inclusion on the left, so we'll define smoothness to be equivalent to smoothness of that composite function. If $F : A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a map from an arbitrary subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, then we'll say that $F$ is smooth if for all $x \in A$ we can find an open set $U \ni x$ and a function $\tilde{F} : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\tilde{F}$ is smooth and $\tilde{F}$ agrees with $F$ on $A$.